# Why not always use weakSelf in a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I understand WHY we would use weakSelf in a block, just not so much when.

I am converting a codebase to ARC which gives a lot of retain cycle warnings with blocks. From the documentation I've gathered that I need to change this:

```
[self.selectedAsset addToFavoritesWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
    self.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;
    [self updateIsFavoriteButton];
}];
```

to this:

```
__weak MyViewController* weakSelf = self;
[self.selectedAsset addToFavoritesWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
    self.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;
    [weakSelf updateIsFavoriteButton];
}];
```

To make the compiler happy and avoid retain loops. My question is why isn't it necessary to change the line:

```
self.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;
```

to use weakSelf? Doesn't it evaluate to a method call as well? Why doesn't the compiler warn about lines in this format?

```
[[self selectedAsset]setIsFavorite:YES];
```

EDIT: I just update to XCode 4.6, and it now generates compiler warnings for just this situation. Funny timing :)

Comment: And then people keep telling me that ARC is much simpler than MRC... -.- Sigh...

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm a happy user of ARC and it works pretty well. Most of the time, I don't have to worry much about memory management. It makes a lot of stuff easier at the cost of making a few things a lot more confusing, like `self` in blocks.

Comment: ARC is much simpler though? This is pretty straight forward stuff, one just needs to know what is going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is why isn't it necessary to change the line:
>
> `self.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;` to use `weakSelf`? Doesn't it
>   evaluate to a method call as well? Why doesn't the compiler warn about
>   lines in this format?
>
> `[[self selectedAsset]setIsFavorite:YES];`

Yes, it is exactly a method call. And it does cause a strong reference to `self`. And it IS necessary to change it to `weakSelf` if you want it to not retain `self`.

Compiler warnings do not catch everything.

Comment: That's what I figured. I just wanted to verify. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the main post to reflect this. I just installed XCode 4.6 and it now generates warnings for this situation.

Comment: So should one always try to change all refs to `weak` for variables that are captured in blocks? Seems like the risk of retain cycles that the programmer hasn't anticipated is high.

Answer (score 1):

```
__weak MyViewController* weakSelf = self;
[self.selectedAsset addToFavoritesWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
    self.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;
    [weakSelf updateIsFavoriteButton];
}];
```

is indeed daft. The completion block referenced self twice, which would create a strong reference. It still references self once, which still creates a strong reference. And weak references are pointless if you are using strong references as well. This should be

```
__weak MyViewController* weakSelf = self;
[self.selectedAsset addToFavoritesWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
    weakSelf.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;
    [weakSelf updateIsFavoriteButton];
}];
```

or better (because safer)

```
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
[self.selectedAsset addToFavoritesWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
    typeof (self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    strongSelf.selectedAsset.isFavorite = YES;
    [strongSelf updateIsFavoriteButton];
}];
```